# Rebuilding the initial message using the payload factory mediator

Tags: wso2, payload

I'm involved in a proxy service development using WSO2.

In my sequence I've saved the initial current message in a property using the following:

```
<property name="InitialMessage" expression="$body" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

and now I need to rebuild the initial message using the payload factory mediator. Am I right? What are some considerable alternatives?

Could someone show me the right syntax in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes your method is correct, But I would suggest you to save only the required properties from your incoming message and use them in building the new message. Sample Syntax is given below

```
<payloadfactory>
      <format>
           <m:checkpriceresponse xmlns:m="http://services.samples/xsd">
               <m:code>$1</m:code>
               <m:price>$2</m:price>
           </m:checkpriceresponse>
      </format>
      <args>
           <arg expression="//m0:symbol" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples/xsd">
           <arg expression="//m0:last" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples/xsd">
      </arg></arg></args>
</payloadfactory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem using the enrich mediator: Here you are how ...

I've saved my initial message in a property InitialMessage in this manner ...

```
<property name="InitialMessage" expression="$body" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

and after I've used the enrich mediator in this manner

```
<enrich>
    <source type="property" clone="true" property="InitialMessage"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

It's working ...

I hope this could be useful ...